# Android json search Displays 2 record when there is just one

Tags: android, arrays, json, filter, textwatcher

Problems:  in Textwatcher
search(filter) show 2 record when data matches the value present in the first name  eq when I type M it will show 2 record for mary but when I type k it show 1 record of mary kom and 2 record of Karl plus 
json data

```
{"details": [

        {
                "id": "01",
                "name": "Mary Kom",
                "email": "abc@uvw.in",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },


        {
                "id": "02",
                "name": "karl plus",
                "email": "pqrp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
]}
```

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     EditText inputSearch;
     ListAdapter adapter;

    // URL to get contacts JSON      
    private static String url = "http://www.abcd.in/api/details";   

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Enabling Search Filter               
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
                // When user change the Text
                ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);        

            }          
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                 
            }             
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable cs) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }
        });

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();


    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                        String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                        String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                        String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                        contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] 
                    { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);                    

        }
}}
```

Comment: I guess a screenshot would be good.

Comment: I am unable to add image as i am new user

Comment: basically the problem is when the character I type matches first name it displays 2 record for the same when there is just 1 record, and when the character matches with last name of the json it displays proper data for the same    eq: when it type ma(refer json obove) it will display 2 record for mary kom but when i type ko it will display 1 record for the same

Comment: i have a issue in textwatcher